# implement an abstract method in derived class as static

Tags: java, inheritance, static, abstract

I have these 2 classes

```
class A {

public void foo1() { 
...;     
foo2();       
...;        
}


protected abstract foo2();

}




class B extends A {

public foo2() {       
......    
}
```

I need foo2 to be static so I can do B.foo2() but I also want the functionality in class A to remain.n

Any suggestions?

}

Comment: There is no `foo2` functionality in class `A` if it's abstract. And `B` must implement `foo2` for the inheritance chain to be valid.

Comment: You can't do the technical thing you asked about (making an abstract method static in a subclass).  But what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?  Ask about the high-level problem you want to solve; don't ask about a perceived technical solution. (See [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)]

Answer (score 0):

You can't override static methods or implement abstract methods as static.

Static methods are defined on a class definition, not on a class instance. Abstract methods are defined on a class instance.

Answer (score 0):

What you said doesn't make sense in fact.

Although I don't quite get why you need to do it, there is a workaround:

```
class B {
    @Override 
    public void foo() {
        fooUtil();
    }

    public static void fooUtil() {
        // your impl here
    }
}
```

Then you can do `B.fooUtil()` instead, and using its behavior to override `A.foo()`.